# Visual Studio 2013 can't find Windows 10 mobile emulator vhd file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, emulation, windows-10-mobile

I want to test my windows mobile application in Windows 10, so I installed the SDK and emulator from Microsoft. Visual Studio 2013 has detected that it's installed, and gives it as an option to use it for testing. However, when I run it, I get the error

> The VHD file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86%\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.14393.0\Flash.vhd does not exist.

The windows 8.1 emulator does not give any problems. Does anyone know what causes this, and how to fix it?

Many thanks,
ydvd

Comment: Could you find `Flash.vhd` file in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\10.0.14393.0` folder?

Comment: Yes, it's there

Comment: I did not think VS 2013 supports the UWP sdk. I think you need it to use the win 10 mobile emulators